# Errors in Forms miss match type

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

```
 details.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest(views.html.adminpages.aboutusimgsForm(errors)),
```

`[NoSuchElementException: None.get]`

From this form

```
@(details: Form[AboutImages])

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@details.get.id">
<input type="text" name="name" value="@details.get.name">
```

I have an edit form `aboutusimgs/edit/1` that adds text and hidden form inputs from the databases(mysql).

But when I don't fill in the form and the error part of the bind executes:

`errors => BadRequest(views.html.adminpages.aboutusimgsForm(errors)),`

I get the `NoSuchElementException` do I have make another form just for errors why can I just use the edit form?

Thanks

Comment: Do you access the form via `value.get` directly in your template?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that if a value is not set, it will have `None` as value. `None.get` always throws a `NoSuchElementException`, because it obviously has no element. You can handle `Option`s in several ways, but if you have a default, you can simply use `getOrElse`. E.g:

```
// first map it to the id, then get the value or default if None
details.map(_.id).getOrElse("")
```

You should also have a look at the the [scala docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) for the `Option` type and read one or two of the several articles about how to use options.

Answer (score 0):

To work with `Option`'s results, you should never ever use `get` method directly.

Why? Because it leads exactly to a potential **NullPointerException** concept from Java (since throwing NoSuchElementException by `None`) => preventing safety in your way of coding.

To retrieve result and especially do something according to the retrieved value, prefer pattern matching or better, the shorter `fold` method:

```
/** Returns the result of applying $f to this $option's
   *  value if the $option is nonempty.  Otherwise, evaluates
   *  expression `ifEmpty`.
   *
   *  @note This is equivalent to `$option map f getOrElse ifEmpty`.
   *
   *  @param  ifEmpty the expression to evaluate if empty.
   *  @param  f       the function to apply if nonempty.
   */
  @inline final def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B): B =
    if (isEmpty) ifEmpty else f(this.get)
```

Alternatively, you can choose to use `getOrElse` method if you only want to retrieve the `Option`'s result and provide a default value if you deal with a `None`:

```
  /** Returns the option's value if the option is nonempty, otherwise
   * return the result of evaluating `default`.
   *
   *  @param default  the default expression.
   */
  @inline final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B =
    if (isEmpty) default else this.get
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `List[Option[String]]` or `Seq` ... the solution would be to use `flatMap` which removes `None` so

```
List(Some("Message"),None).map{ _.get.split(" ") } //throws error
```

but if you use flatmap

```
List(Some("Message"),None).flatMap{ i => i }.map{ _.split(" ") } //Executes without errors
```